# Get Value Of Custom Layout Update Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]
Hello guys I am new in Magento I want to get value of "Custom Layout Update" attribute. How can I achieve this in magento 1?
I tried like this but I get error

```
foreach ($products->getItems() as $item) {
  $att_value = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
  ->load($item->getId)
  ->getAttribute('layoutUpdate_validator')->getSource()
  ->getOptionText($item->getData('layoutUpdate_validator'));
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento get any product information by load product model as

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCTID);
```

where replace PRODUCTID with product entity id.
Get any product attribute data by `$_product->getData(ATTRIBUTENAME);` 
Here for get **Custom Layout Update** use `$_product->getData('custom_layout_update');` or `$_product->getCustomLayoutUpdate();`

Comment: You are great. Thank you very much. That was what I needed.